# How to read a vector of vector of Point - c++

Tags: c++, exception, opencv, vector

I have a vector of vectors of `Point` (called `squares`, returned by `findSquares()` function of `squares.cpp` (OpenCV)).

I want to do an average of x and y coordinates of four points stored in the vector of Point (in c++ language).

I tried to do this:

```
    vector <Point> coordinates(4);

    for ( int i = 0; i<squares.size();i++) {

        coordinates[0].x += squares[i][0].x;
        coordinates[0].y += squares[i][0].y;

        coordinates[1].x += squares[i][1].x;
        coordinates[1].y += squares[i][1].y;

        coordinates[2].x += squares[i][2].x;
        coordinates[2].y += squares[i][2].y;

        coordinates[3].x += squares[i][3].x;
        coordinates[3].y += squares[i][3].y;
    } 
    if(squares.size() !=0){
        for( int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            coordinates[j].x /= squares.size();
            coordinates[j].y /= squares.size();
        }
    }
```

but I get this Exception :

[image]

I'm reading elements of the vector of vector of Point in a wrong way?

Comment: Can you show the procedure that creates `squares`?

Comment: `vector<vector<Point> > squares;
findSquares(image,squares);`

You can find `findSquares(...)` function at this link: [https://projects.developer.nokia.com/opencv/browser/opencv/opencv-2.3.1/samples/cpp/squares.cpp]

Comment: Andy meant: How do you *fill* the squares? Or don't you fill this vector? I think it's the function `findSquares()` we have to see.

Comment: @Cristina1986: What I would like to see is the code for `findSquares()`

Comment: Please remove the `[]` from your comment; the `]` gets included within the link and so it doesn't work unless removed.

Comment: I would be interested in why you're not just assigning `Point`'s straight across, or better, entire rows, if needed. Provided `Point` is properly copyable, this should be trivial.

Comment: @Cristina1986: Somehow I cannot open that link. Anyway, I believe the problem is that `squares` contains vectors of the wrong size. Try to check what is the size of the vectors contained by `squares` (in particular, if they contain at least 4 elements).

Comment: @AndyProwl There was a `]` in the link. https://projects.developer.nokia.com/opencv/browser/opencv/opencv-2.3.1/samples/cpp/squares.cpp

Comment: https://projects.developer.nokia.com/opencv/browser/opencv/opencv-2.3.1/samples/cpp/squares.cpp

Comment: @Cristina1986: Have you tried debugging it? What is the line that triggers the assertion?

Comment: the line is the first within for loop:
`coordinates[0].x += squares[i][0].x`;

Comment: Try to do `std::cout << squares[i].size()` to see what is the size of the vector `square[i]`. My bet is that it is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to the following code:

```
if (squares.size() !=0){
    for( int j=0; j<4; j++) {
        coordinates[j].x /= squares.size();
        coordinates[j].y /= squares.size();
    }
}
```

**This block of code can crash at `coordinates[j].x` when `squares.size()` is bigger than 0 but less then 4.**

Imagine that `squares.size()` is 2. What do you think it will happen in the `for` loop when `j` becomes 2? The division will become `coordinates[2].x /= squares.size();`, which attempts to access a position in the vector that doesn't exist, causing the crash. **Remember**: If the size of the array is 2, the valid indexes of the vector are 0 and 1, so 2 is out of range.

This is a problem in your code and could be what's causing the crash. To fix it update your loop to be:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < squares.size(); j++) {
```

If the crash continues to happen, the problem lies somewhere else in your code.